# how to truncate a string using regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string in a file and want to truncate the string to no more than 6 char. how to do that using regular expression in perl?
the original file is:

cat shortstring.in:

`<value>1234@google.com</value>

              <value>1235@google.com</value>`

I want to get file as:
cat shortstring.out

`<value>1234@g</value>

              <value>1235@g</value>`

I have a code as follows, is there any more efficient way than using
`s/<value>(\w\w\w\w\w\w)(.*)/$1/;`?

Here is a part of my code:

```
    while (<$input_handle>) {                        # take one input line at a time
            chomp;
            if (/(\d+@google.com)/) {
                    s/(<value>\w\w\w\w\w\w)(.*)</value>/$1/;
                    print $output_handle "$_\n";
              } else {
              print $output_handle "$_\n";
            }
    }
```

Comment: @ is not a word character so isn't matched by \w.  Also, I think you don't mean to remove the `<value>` part?

Answer (score 10):

Use this instead (regex is not the only feature of Perl and it's overkill for this: :-)

```
$str = substr($str, 0, 6);
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: +1 for reminding me that regex is not the only feature of Perl .-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -pe 's/(<value>[^<]{1,6})[^<]*/$1/' shortstring.in
<value>1234@g</value>
<value>1235@g</value>
```

In the context of the snippet from your question, use

```
while (<$input_handle>) {
  s!(<value>)(.*?)(</value>)!$1 . substr($2,0,6) . $3!e
    if /(\d+\@google\.com)/;
  print $output_handle $_;
}
```

or to do it with a single pattern

```
while (<$input_handle>) {
   s!(<value>)(\d+\@google\.com)(</value>)!$1 . substr($2,0,6) . $3!e;
  print $output_handle $_;
}
```

Using bangs as the delimiters on the substitution operator prevents [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) in `</value>`.

**NOTE:** The usual [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) about “parsing” XML with regular expressions apply.

Demo program:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $input_handle = \*DATA;
open my $output_handle, ">&=", \*STDOUT or die "$0: open: $!";

while (<$input_handle>) {
   s!(<value>)(\d+\@google\.com)(</value>)!$1 . substr($2,0,6) . $3!e;
  print $output_handle $_;
}

__DATA__
<value>1234@google.com</value>
<value>1235@google.com</value>
<value>12@google.com</value>
```

Output:

```
$ ./prog.pl 
<value>1234@g</value>
<value>1235@g</value>
<value>12@goo</value>
```

Comment: I think my code is not correct, I only want to truncate the data between <value></value>

Comment: your does not work. finally I use this:  s/(<value>.{1,$truncate_num}).*(<.*)/$1$2/;

Comment: @gbacon thanks for the updated s!!!e sytnax.  Someone else had posted then deleted that, but it didn't include the "<value>" tags.  Had never used s!!!e before and was curious on how that would have looked if done correctly.

Comment: @David Perl is flexible about the delimiters on the `s///` operator. Using bangs meant I didn't have to escape the slash in `</value>`.

Comment: @lilili08 See updated answer for a working program that includes the code I suggested. What's the output you're seeing?

Comment: @gbacon The various separator parts I knew, the 'e' flag is the gem I've wanted several times and did not known how to do.  Loving stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to truncate the text inside the  tag which could be shorter than 6 characters already, in which case:

```
s/(<value>[^<]{1,6})[^<]*/$1/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s|(?<=<value>)(.*?)(?=</value>)|substr $1,0,6|e;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/<value>(.{1,6}).*/<value>$1</value>/;
```

Comment: With the . in (.{1,6}) you could get stuff like '123</v'

Comment: @David, no, because he's already tested to make sure the tag has `@google.com`, so it can't be smaller than that.  If you want to more careful, you could test for the closing tag, but since parsing xml or html in a regex is a REALLY REALLY BAD IDEA anyway, I don't want to give him any ideas.